# unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused) Laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp

Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused)

I tried to send email using laravel but i could not able to send email using godaddy Shared Hosting.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: Try to use PORT : 587 and ENCRYPTION: TLS.

Comment: Open this link: https://google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps Click on Enable. And save it. Then try to send email again. For me it worked

Comment: I already did this step did not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

Or better:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=secret@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but did not work for me.

Comment: Try to put wrong credentials to see if error change

Comment: Still very confused as to why 465 works fine in my development environment but not in production... but 587 works on both. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue during development in localhost. I would wanted to test sending of emails from my application using laravel SMTP mailer. Finally the solution was that I added verify_peer and verify_peer_name fields with the value false to SMPTconfig in config/mail.php.

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
            'verify_peer' => env('MAIL_VALIDATE_CERT',  false),
            'verify_peer_name' => env('MAIL_VALIDATE_CERT',  false)
        ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should surround them with "", I don't know why but it worked to my case.

```
MAIL_DRIVER="smtp"
MAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
MAIL_PORT="465"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="ssl"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

in the `.env` file change the driver to `sendmail`
if Gmail has 2fa make sure you create an app password and use that password instead of your Gmail password in the `.env` file.

Cheers

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=***********
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL/TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=a*****************
MAIL_FROM_NAME="***************"
```